# Read YAML field from LaTeX

Tags: luatex, compiling, external-files

Let me explain my problem. I have a simple YAML file automatically generated with a series of experiments that looks like as follows

```
error-metric1:
    method1: value
    method2: value
    method3: value

error-metric2:
    method1: value
    method2: value
    method3: value
```

What I would like to do is to - somehow - retrieve values automatically from the file during compilation and insert them in text and/or tables. For example, I'm looking to do something like:

```
The error rate for the method1 is \readYAML{file}{error-metric1}{method1}
```

First question: do you think it is possible? Do you have any suggestions on how it can be done?

BTW, if this might help, my workflow is based on LuaLaTeX. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Will each metric always have the same number of methods, or might the number of methods vary with the metric?  Also, are the words "error-metric" and "method" standard words that actually appear in the file, or are you only using them as placeholder words?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a complete YAML parser, but this should be sufficient for your specific need. I used `\jobname` just not to clobber my files, you can use your own files.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.yaml}
error-metric1:
    method1: 1
    method2: 2
    method3: 3

error-metric2:
    method1: 4
    method2: 5
    method3: 6
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\readYAML}{mmm}
 {% #1 = file (no .yaml extension)
  % #2 = section
  % #3 = key
  \sr_readyaml:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__sr_readyaml_currsection_tl
\seq_new:N \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq
\ior_new:N \g_sr_readyaml_stream

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cxx }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_blank:n { f } { TF }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sr_readyaml:nnn
 {
  \prop_if_exist:cF { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop }
   {
    \__sr_readyaml_read:n { #1 }
   }
  \prop_item:cn { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop } { #2@#3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sr_readyaml_read:n
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop }
  \ior_open:Nn \g_sr_readyaml_stream { #1.yaml }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_sr_readyaml_stream
   {
    \__sr_readyaml_line:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_sr_readyaml_stream
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sr_readyaml_line:nn
 {% #1 is the file name, #2 the current line
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_set_split:NVn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq \c_colon_str { #2 }
    \tl_if_blank:fTF { \seq_item:Nn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq { 2 } }
     {% nothing after the colon, set the current section
      \tl_set:Nx \l__sr_readyaml_currsection_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq { 1 } }
     }
     {% value after the colon, add to the property list
      \prop_gput:cxx
       % prop name
       { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop }
       % key
       { \l__sr_readyaml_currsection_tl @ \seq_item:Nn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq { 1 } }
       % value
       { \seq_item:Nn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq { 2 } }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\readYAML{\jobname}{error-metric1}{method1} \par
\readYAML{\jobname}{error-metric1}{method2} \par
\readYAML{\jobname}{error-metric1}{method3} \par
\readYAML{\jobname}{error-metric2}{method1} \par
\readYAML{\jobname}{error-metric2}{method2} \par
\readYAML{\jobname}{error-metric2}{method3} \par

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to split off the reading phase from the data retrieving phase, in order to get an expandable macro.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.yaml}
error-metric1:
    method1: 1
    method2: 2
    method3: 3

error-metric2:
    method1: 4
    method2: 5
    method3: 6
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\readYAML}{m}
 {% #1 = file (no .yaml extension)
  \sr_readyaml:n { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getfromYAML}{mmm}
 {% #1 = file (no .yaml extension)
  % #2 = section
  % #3 = key
  \prop_item:cn { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop } { #2@#3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__sr_readyaml_currsection_tl
\seq_new:N \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq
\ior_new:N \g_sr_readyaml_stream

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cxx }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_blank:n { f } { TF }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sr_readyaml:n
 {
  \prop_if_exist:cF { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop }
   {
    \__sr_readyaml_read:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sr_readyaml_read:n
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop }
  \ior_open:Nn \g_sr_readyaml_stream { #1.yaml }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_sr_readyaml_stream
   {
    \__sr_readyaml_line:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_sr_readyaml_stream
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sr_readyaml_line:nn
 {% #1 is the file name, #2 the current line
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_set_split:NVn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq \c_colon_str { #2 }
    \tl_if_blank:fTF { \seq_item:Nn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq { 2 } }
     {% nothing after the colon, set the current section
      \tl_set:Nx \l__sr_readyaml_currsection_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq { 1 } }
     }
     {% value after the colon, add to the property list
      \prop_gput:cxx
       % prop name
       { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop }
       % key
       { \l__sr_readyaml_currsection_tl @ \seq_item:Nn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq { 1 } }
       % value
       { \seq_item:Nn \l__sr_readyaml_line_seq { 2 } }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% read the file
\readYAML{\jobname}

\getfromYAML{\jobname}{error-metric1}{method1} \par
\getfromYAML{\jobname}{error-metric1}{method2} \par
\getfromYAML{\jobname}{error-metric1}{method3} \par
\getfromYAML{\jobname}{error-metric2}{method1} \par
\getfromYAML{\jobname}{error-metric2}{method2} \par
\getfromYAML{\jobname}{error-metric2}{method3} \par

\end{document}
```

If you add, before `\ExplSyntaxOff`

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\printYAML}{mm}
 {% #1 = YAML file, #2 = property
  \begin{itemize}
  \prop_map_inline:cn { g_sr_readyaml_#1_prop }
   {
    \str_if_in:nnT { ##1 } { #2@ } { \item \__sr_readyaml_entry:n { ##1 }:~##2 }
   }
  \end{itemize}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__sr_readyaml_entry:n
 {
  \__sr_readyaml_entry:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__sr_readyaml_entry:w #1 @ #2 \q_stop { #2 }
```

then the call

```
\printYAML{\jobname}{error-metric1}
```

would print

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to use this to return _all_ key value pairs, i.e., {error-metric1}{value_i_} for i = 1 to _n_, where n is unknown?

Comment: @AndyClifton Does the edit answer your question? Otherwise, please open a new question with the details of the specification.

Comment: Thanks @egreg - seems to. I'll review for my case and may submit a new question.

Answer (score 5):

See the example below using [LYAML](https://github.com/gvvaughan/lyaml), tested on Debian 11 (bullseye).

Some notes:

1. You need the [LYAML](https://github.com/gvvaughan/lyaml) (LibYAML
   binding for Lua) Lua library, and the [Lua
   POSIX](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) library. These
   correspond to the Lua libraries lua-yaml and lua-posix in Debian and
   derivatives. Depending   on your OS/distribution, these may be
   available for your OS/distribution, otherwise you will have to
   install them.
2. Including the `luapackageloader` package is important, because
   otherwise the external Lua packages will not be found. As you
   can see, I've added additional search paths for Lua in
   `util.lua`, but without that package they will be ignored. See
   `texdoc luapackageloader` for further information.
3. It is customary to add a TeX wrapper for Lua functions when
   exposing them to TeX (in this case, `\readYAML`), which usually
   goes into a .sty file. But in this case, I just included it in the
   TeX file for simplicity.
4. I've included `sr.yaml` (the YAML file), along with `util.lua` (the
   LUA file), in the TeX file `sr.tex` using the builtin `filecontents`
   command, for simplicity. This will will create the files `sr.yaml` and
   `util.lua`, provided the `-shell-escape` option to `lualatex` is used.
5. You need to call this using `lualatex -shell-escape sr.tex`

   ```
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %% sr.tex
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{luapackageloader} % Required for Lua to look in standard
                                 % Lua paths.
   \begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{sr.yaml}
   error-metric1:
       method1: fee
       method2: fi
       method3: fum

   error-metric2:
       method1: foo
       method2: bar
       method3: baz
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{util.lua}
   package.cpath="/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3/?.so;\z
   /usr/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so;./?.so"..package.cpath
   package.path="/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;\z
   /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;\z
   /usr/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua"..package.path

   local function loadYAML(config)
      local lyaml = require "lyaml"
      local posix = require "posix"
      local s
      if posix.stat(config) ~= nil then
         local f = io.open(config)
         s = f:read("*all")
         f:close()
         return lyaml.load (s)
      end
   end

   local function readYAML(config, keyA, keyB)
      tex.sprint(loadYAML(config)[keyA][keyB])
   end

   return {readYAML=readYAML}
   \end{filecontents}

   \directlua{util_lualib = require "util"}
   \NewDocumentCommand{\readYAML}{m m m}
   {
     \directlua{util_lualib.readYAML("\luaescapestring{#1}",
     "\luaescapestring{#2}", "\luaescapestring{#3}")}%
   }

   \begin{document}
   The error rate for the method1 is 
   \readYAML{sr.yaml}{error-metric1}{method1}.
   \end{document}

   %%% Local Variables:
   %%% mode: latex
   %%% TeX-engine: luatex
   %%% TeX-master: t
   %%% End:
   ```

[image]